# Visual Basic 2008 , Search for an image on my desktop ( getpixel way/ comparing pixels)

Tags: vb.net, image, compare, pixel, getpixel

i'm a young "programmer" and i'm trying to make a code that searches if a 400 x 500 image (a bmp file from my computer ) appears on the screen .

The code looks like this  :

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Dim-ing section'
    Dim scrsize As Size = New Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim scrtake = New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory, "fishbot.bmp")
    Dim resource As New Bitmap(path)

    Dim a As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(scrtake)
    Dim b As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(resource)

    a.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), scrsize)



   'as a test to see if the code is compiled until here'
    Me.BackgroundImage = scrtake 
   'end test'

    For x As Integer = 100 To scrsize.Height - 400
        For y As Integer = 300 To scrsize.Width - 300
            For x1 As Integer = 0 To resource.Height
                For y1 As Integer = 0 To resource.Width
                    If scrtake.GetPixel(x, y) = resource.GetPixel(x1, y1) Then
                        TextBox1.Text = "found"

                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next







End Sub
```

Also , the elements are already on the form .

```
 For x As Integer = 100 To scrsize.Height - 400
            For y As Integer = 300 To scrsize.Width - 300
                For x1 As Integer = 0 To resource.Height
                    For y1 As Integer = 0 To resource.Width
                    If scrtake.GetPixel(x, y) = resource.GetPixel(x1, y1) Then
                        TextBox1.Text = "found"

                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

This code returns :" Parameter must be positive and < Height. Parameter name: y " and i can't find a solution . Also checked lots of sites and still nothing
And if you know a better comparation system for pixels or something to improve speed , share with me :) .

Comment: that kind of message is often generated by vb's cgi wrapper, somewhere in there you're either trying to create a bitmap smaller than 1x1 or probing for a pixel outside the bitmaps bounds

Answer (score 1):

ok looked over your code

For x1 As Integer = 0 To resource.Height

should be

For x1 As Integer = 0 To resource.Height - 1
etc

a 100x100 bitmap would have the addressable area of 0-99 x 0-99 as 0 is also a valid index